# NAudio - Get Peak Values for ASIO input device

Tags: c#, naudio, naudio-framework

I know how to use `AudioMeterInformation.PeakValues` to get the level of an input channel with a WASAPI device, but how can I do this with an ASIO device? Is there a method built into to do it or will I have to write something?

best,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Basically with ASIO, you need to start recording which will give you access to the raw samples, and you can use this to update level meters. This is how most DAWs will work - they will always be "recording" in that they are monitoring the inputs on the ASIO device, and so the only difference when you press "record" is that now it's writing it to disk as well.